# Error upgrading to Spring Boot 2.7.8 from 2.7.7

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a project using Spring Boot 2.7.7 and MongoDB. I'm using the following pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>XXXXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXXX</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>XXXX</name>
    <description>XXXX</description>

    <properties>
        <kotlin.version>1.8.10</kotlin.version>
        <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
        <spring.cloud.stream.version>3.1.2</spring.cloud.stream.version>
        <release.train.version>2021.0.5</release.train.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.8</jacoco.version>
        <skip-jacoco>false</skip-jacoco>
        <surefireArgLine></surefireArgLine>
        <failsafeArgLine></failsafeArgLine>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-kotlin-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-extra</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-gateway-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-reactor</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot</groupId>
            <artifactId>iot-service-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.26.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Kafka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.cloud.stream.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.cloud.stream.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
            <artifactId>proton-j</artifactId>
            <version>0.33.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.cloud.stream.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentracing.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-opentracing</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentracing-mongo-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WebClient testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockwebserver3-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-alpha.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ninja-squad</groupId>
            <artifactId>springmockk</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>archunit-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>0.22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger generation and UI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-kotlin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${release.train.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <wait>1000</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>180</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>no-arg</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <pluginOptions>
                        <option>no-arg:annotation=com.telefonica.haac.platform.filemon.common.core.mapping.Mappable</option>
                    </pluginOptions>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/test/kotlin/unit</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>src/test/kotlin/integration</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>src/test/kotlin/common</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>src/test/kotlin/arch</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>@{surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*UnitTest.*</include>
                        <include>**/*ArchTest.*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <properties>
                        <configurationParameters>
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = same_thread
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>@{failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IntegrationTest.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${skip-jacoco}</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${skip-jacoco}</skip>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${skip-jacoco}</skip>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${skip-jacoco}</skip>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                            <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${skip-jacoco}</skip>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Detekt for check-styles -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.ozsie</groupId>
                <artifactId>detekt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <baseline>${basedir}/build-config/detekt-baseline.xml</baseline>
                    <config>${basedir}/build-config/detekt.yml</config>
                    <autoCorrect>true</autoCorrect>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals><goal>check</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <report>
                                <report>html:${project.build.directory}/reports/detekt/detekt-report.html</report>
                                <report>xml:${project.build.directory}/reports/detekt/detekt-report.xml</report>
                            </report>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>detekt-formatting</artifactId>
                        <version>1.21.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <apiDocsUrl>${springdoc.url}</apiDocsUrl>
                    <outputFileName>${springdoc.filename}.json</outputFileName>
                    <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/springdoc/openapi3/</outputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This works without any problem. However, just upgrading to Spring Boot 2.7.8 I start getting a lots of failures in the tests with this message:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class [Lorg.bson.Document;.)
```

This seems very strange as the class `org.bson.Document` is in the core of the MongoDB driver. We don't have any custom codec configuration for MongoDB neither. However, maybe I'm missing some change that I need to apply to my pom.xml so it can read it correctly.

Thanks for your help.